# How to find the location of a graph in a Spreadsheet using openpyxl and Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I've got a bit of a problem tracking down Graphs created in large spreadsheets, often with multiple sheets. Having a graph in these spreadsheets often causes functionality issues with our in-house apps, and so I began writing a method to hunt them down, but at present I'm getting a result that (despite reading openpyxl's documentation) I do not fully understand.

The routine appears to find a graph but returns a "TwoCellAnchor" which is a type that I don't appear to be able to figure out its construction and/or how to get useful information from (apologies for grammar here).

Here's the code as it stands - I imported TwoCellAnchor to see if I could get some clarity but that didn't help me.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.drawing.spreadsheet_drawing import TwoCellAnchor

# Load the workbook
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("random_objects.xlsx")

# Loop through each sheet in the workbook
for sheet in workbook.worksheets:
    # Iterate over all charts in the sheet
     for chart in sheet._charts:  # type: ignore
    #     cell2 = TwoCellAnchor
    #     # Get the cell where the chart is located
         cell2 = sheet[chart.anchor]
    #     # Print the cell address and the chart type
         print(f"Chart found in cell {cell2}: ")
```

When I run the code above, I get the error as per below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Scripts\Python-New\ExcelModelCheck\chart_checker.py", line 13, in <module>
    cell2 = sheet[chart.anchor]
            ~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Scripts\Python-New\ExcelModelCheck\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 295, in __getitem__
    min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(key)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Scripts\Python-New\ExcelModelCheck\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\cell.py", line 133, in range_boundaries    
    m = ABSOLUTE_RE.match(range_string)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'TwoCellAnchor'
```

What is a TwoCellAnchor and what do I do with it (i.e. How do I return the cell to which the graph is anchored, which is presumably one of the Two Cells referred to, and what does the other cell contain)?

Comment: TwoCellAnchor means that the top left and bottom right of the chart is anchored to cells. Usually you might only have one anchor at top left. This is noted in the Openpyxl documentation at [Positioning Charts with Anchors](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/anchors.html?highlight=TwoCellAnchor#positioning-charts-with-anchors) which also lists the corresponding Excel layout equivalents.

Comment: This information does not appear to be easily available in Openpyxl. You would probably need to do some research into what and where to access the details. If you can use Xlwings that would be easier.